# How is the VM and the local machine connect with each other?

Tags: linux, macos, web-services, laravel, virtual-machine

## VM

I have a web service that need to run on CentOS **VM**.

---

## Mac OS X

On the other hand, I have a Laravel project running my Mac OS X in local machine through MAMP.

The project working great with MAMP. Now, I need to make a API call to the web service that're currently running in the **VM**.

---

I'm curious how is the VM and the local machine connect with each other.

How do I solve that ?

I'm not a linux/VM expert.

Any hints / suggestion on that will be much appreciated !

Comment: You can set your network as bridged in VM software. It will make your host and guest environment as they are connected via LAN.

Comment: NAT should work also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple days of researching and experimenting, I be able to do it.

---

**grabbing the IP**

run `ifconfig` and look for `inet addr:172.16.67.137` of eth0

---

**Disabled firewall on the VM**

[image]

---

**Result**

On a Mac just go to that URL

[image]